# Minimal working example for phylogenetic tree construction in R using an alignment of DNA strings and a vector of names?

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny

I am looking at how to build a `phylogenetic tree` in `R` from **aligned** genetic information (dna sequences). There are multiple tutorials on how to go about this task eg [tutorial1](https://yulab-smu.github.io/treedata-book/chapter2.html), [tutorial2 ("ape" docs)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ape/ape.pdf), [tutorial3](http://www.phytools.org/Cordoba2017/ex/2/Intro-to-phylogenies.html), and there are many more. There appears to be quite a few steps with dependencies from multiple packages: eg. "ape", "phangorn", "phytools", "geiger". I would like to learn a minimal working example (mwe) for constructing a phylogenetic tree from a basic data-structure holding dna-strings.

Eg. I have a vector of nucleotide strings, and a separate vector for the 'names' of each string in the vector, how can I construct a phylogenetic tree from this information? (not a fasta file)

Answer (score 1):

A key difference from many examples provided is that they assume that the data provided is in the form of sequences rather than an already aligned sequence alignment.

```
library("Biostrings")
library("seqinr")
library("ape")
library(phylogram)
library("dendextend")


#read in the data from a format with the aligned sequences (eg msf)
msf.res <- read.alignment(file = "geneticAlignment.msf", format = "msf")
#dist.alignment and not dna.dist commonly used in tutorials
msf.res.dist.alignment = dist.alignment(msf.res, matrix = "identity")
#perform neighbor joining upon the distance set
msf.res.dist.alignment.nj = nj(msf.res.dist.alignment)
#then plot the joined sequences
plot(msf.res.dist.alignment.nj, main = "Neighbor Joining")
```